# Fps shoots up when sdl2 window is not on top

Tags: c++, sdl2

I am learning sdl2 with C++ from Lazy Foo Productions' tutorials. I am using a 5 year old retina mac book pro and xcode.

When reading [this](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/24_calculating_frame_rate/index.php) entry on calculating frame rate I noticed that when runing the application it would tend to 60 fps and the cpu and energy impact were very low, 2% and Low respectively, but when placing another window over it the fps would shoot up to 5000 along with cpu and energy impact, to 93% and High respectively.

Why is this happening? Is it because sdl2 just stops rendering all together when it is not on top of other windows? Or is it because the OS stops it from rendering?

Comment: SDL probably tries to render the scene, but everything gets clipped on the GPU

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a complicated question to answer. There could be multiple possible explanations, including SDL2, the OS, and your graphics driver.

Either way, it sounds like Vsync is on which is intentionally limiting your frame rate which is limiting the executions of your core loop per second which is limiting your CPU usage. When rendering is turned off nothing restricts your core loop from executing as fast as it can and so your CPU usage spikes up.

If you want to experiment with turning off Vsync you can choose not to pass the `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` flag into [SDL_CreateRenderer](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer) or (if you are using SDL2 with OpenGL) using [SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval). If Vsync is still on it might be your graphics driver enforcing it, in which case you would have to configure your driver (this occurs in my case on Windows with SDL2 and the most recent Nvidia drivers for my card), but either way keeping Vsync on is probably good in general.

If you want your CPU usage to not spike whenever rendering is turned off, you could look into trying to inspect [window events](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEventID) or check your window status using [SDL_GetWindowFlags](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowFlags). Most likely a flag like `SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN` is on whenever SDL is rendering and a flag like `SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN` is on whenever it isn't. Every frame, if the 'is-not-displaying' flag is on, you could do something like `SDL_Delay(16)` to limit the frame rate at ~60fps when rendering is off.